# Javascript error embedding redbubble

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Hi I am trying to embed the redbubble code into my site for a client (his red bubble store) into a joomla site and there is something wrong with the script.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.redbubble.com/assets/external_portfolio.js"></script>
<script id="rb-xzfcxvzx" type="text/javascript">new RBExternalPortfolio('www.redbubble.com', 'classiceggshell', 5, 5).renderIframe();</script>
```

The link it includes returns a 404 error when I check it on the devtools in chrome I tested the script on Jslint it gave me these eight warnings
    Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'.
    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
    Missing semicolon.
    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
    Missing semicolon.
    Missing semicolon.
    Unclosed regular expression.
    Unrecoverable syntax error. (85% scanned).

So is there something fundamentally wrong with the code would anyone please be able to fix this and give me the correct code to connect to his store. I have tried to load the link to his store into an Iframe but I think redbubble have a block on the iframes as the iframe wont load and has a X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN error.

I have tried speaking to the support for redbubble and they are still yet to get back to me

Please be aware when replying that although I do have some knowledge and can follow step by step instructions I have very little coding knowledge as normally things like this are straightforward.

Comment: check the documentation.. the script you are referencing on `src` of your script tag does not exist..  `http://www.redbubble.com/assets/external_portfolio.js`

Comment: What documentation? Can you please provide a link?

Answer (score 2):

Alright I had the same issue, for some reason the script isn't there but I was able to find it:

```
RBExternalPortfolio = function(t, e, n, i) {
    var a = this;
    a.domain = t, a.rows = n, a.columns = i, a.user_name = e, a.getHeight = function() {
        return 222 * a.rows + 85
    }, a.getWidth = function() {
        return 240 * a.columns + 26
    }, a.getSrc = function() {
        return "http://" + a.domain + "/people/" + a.user_name + "/external-portfolio?count=" + a.rows * a.columns
    }, a.createIframe = function() {
        var t = document.createElement("iframe");
        return t.src = a.getSrc(), t.width = a.getWidth(), t.height = a.getHeight(), t.frameBorder = 0, t.scrolling = "no", t.setAttribute("allowtransparency", "true"), t
    }, a.renderIframe = function() {
        var t = document.getElementById("rb-xzfcxvzx");
        t.parentNode.replaceChild(a.createIframe(), t)
    }
};
```

From: http://nerdyjs.com/script/1406714

I then saved a copy locally, and changed the getSrc line to hardcode point to my folio, like this:

```
return "http://redbubble.com/people/<yourname>/external-portfolio?count=" + a.rows * a.columns
```

It sucks that they haven't fixed it yet but the code at least is out there!